# php - store part of object chain in variable?

Tags: php

Using an [image library](https://github.com/Intervention/image), I was wondering if I could store part of the object chain in a variable (which could then reside in the database) and use it again afterwards. I'm not sure if it is even called this way, but found no other information.

What I'm trying to accomplish:

```
$extra = "fit(800, 500, null)->limitColors(5, '#ff9900')->invert()";
$image = $manager->make($source)->$extra;
echo $image->response('jpg', 85);
```

To get to this result:

```
$image = $manager->make($source)->fit(800, 500, null)->limitColors(5, '#ff9900')->invert();
echo $image->response('jpg', 85);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you cant store `"fit(800, 500, null)->limitColors(5, '#ff9900')->invert()";` in a variable. If you store this in a variable it will treat as string and it returns nothing. If you want it to return what you want you need the help of `$manager` instance and `make()` method. So you cant store only this part `fit(800, 500, null)->limitColors(5, '#ff9900')->invert()` in a variable and use it.

```
$source = $manager->make($source);
$added_extra = $source->fit(800, 500, null)->limitColors(5, '#ff9900')->invert();
$image = $added_extra->response('jpg', 85);
echo $image;
```

Comment: Ok, I understand so far - but how would I include both $manager and $make() and the other parameters - and still be able to build a valid method chain?

Comment: @Taapo do the way it is. I think that is the best way

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off (clearer code, easier re-use) to not do this. If you need to do this one specific thing over and over again, you might want to make a function:

```
$image = $manager->make($source)->$extra;
echo editImage($image)->response('jpg', 85);

function editImage(\Intervention\Image $image){
  return $image->fit(800, 500, null)->limitColors(5, '#ff9900')->invert();
}
```

Everywhere you need to call that specific fit/colors/invert chain, you can call your function.

If you have to do this fit and limit etc absolutely everytime before you echo your response, you can go a step further: 
You can make a child-classs of `Intervention\Image;`, where you override the response class (I think, not sure if there is a better one, you should check the actual library) and make call those three functions internally?

That might be overkill though.

As response to your comment: you could do it like so:

```
function editImage(\Intervention\Image $image, YourSettingsObject $settings){
  return $image
    ->fit($settings->width, $settings->height, $settings->something)
    ->limitColors($settings->limit, $settings->color)
    ->invert();
```

}
    }

Here I assume you create a class for the settings and you fill it from your database. You could just as easy use an array of course. There are some side-points you should take into account (like sane defaults for a non-existent value in the settings object), and you could expand this function with whatever you need to add to you settings object.

so what you do is create your first `$image`, and get your `$settings` object from the database (or array if you're so inclined), and give those to a function. You're calling all the `fit`, `limitColors` etc only once, based on these settings.

Comment: In understand the way of wrapping it in a function - but how can I store the chain elements in a database and reload them from there when needed? Then I'm back to using variables to build the chain.

Comment: You should make a special function for that. I can give you an example, just a sec

Comment: Very nice, thanks for the example - much clearer now. I still have the problem of the manipulations that I need to store in a database as well and recall, like "fit", "limitColors" and "invert" ... is there a way to store those values as well?

Comment: I would not save the actual commands in the database, because you would be bound to go to some sort of eval system. Just save a number for 'fit' in the database (column)

Answer (score -1):

Probably what you need to use is [`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php), but as of what `PHP` website states and quoting:

> The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged.

long story short you can do it this way if you are aware of the consequences and still need it:

```
$extra = "fit(800, 500, null)->limitColors(5, '#ff9900')->invert()";
$image = eval('$manager->make($source)->'.$extra);
```

Comment: Yes, I thought this would be a way of doing it, but wanted to find out if there was another way for obvious reasons - thanks for the tip!

Comment: what are the variables in `$extra`?

Comment: Trying it your way, I get an error:  "PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function response() on boolean". And $extra is the variable.